# VBA store specific strings into Array that follow specific character

Tags: vba

VBA Masters,

I have a merged range in Excel (A1:D7) that has a varying number of lines of text. Each new line of text starts with a "*" to denote the beginning of a new statement.

I need to be able to store each of those statements in a variable and write them out to their own individual cells rather than having it in the merged cell area.

I've attached an image of an example of the block of text.

[image]

Comment: use `split()` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/split-function

Comment: To add, the return of `split()` will be an `array`, this is essentially a range, so you can "paste" using code via `.value`

Comment: Make sure that your "pasting" range is the same as your array's range. As you cannot give it only the first cell and expect it to "paste" in the following cells.